# How much can an iOS developer charge?

Tags: contracts, pay-rate

Based on my research, I have determined that an iOS programmer can earn 4000 EUR / month in the EU in a full time job. This is 25 EUR / hour.

How much of a premium should a programmer charge for short-term (i.e. only hours or days) consulting? Are there any sites that provide IT consultant rates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not pertaining to iOS specifically, but freelancing in general, also as a citizen/resident of the USA, I would charge roughly 4 times the hourly rate you get from an employer. I've seen other freelancers charge around this much.

So if an iOS dev is making 25EUR/hour, then as freelance, said dev would charge 100EUR/hour.

This may seem high, but there are few reasons to charge this:

1. You have to bring in the same salary, so you will charge 25EUR/hour minimum.
2. You have taxes, insurance, infrastructure investment, and other liabilities, this can come near your take home pay.
3. You will not likely bill for full-time hours, so you have to account for all the unpaid work you will do. Freelancers do a lot, up to 50%, of unbillable work.

Of course there is latitude in how much you charge, but hiring a freelance shouldn't be assumed to be cheaper for the customer, or more/less lucrative for the developer. The benefit of freelancing is freedom in working how you would like work, or working with someone who can work with or around you more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Rate is dictated in majority by experience and locality/geography.
iOS and Android carry the same rate burden in most cases.
I will site examples for three major metro areas on the West Coast, USA:
+These are observations based on my 15 years recruiting experience and can vary of course by the client/company and project duration (if Contract) and role designation - like a team lead, etc.

The SF Bay Area
Experience 3-8 years
Contract: 50-160hr
FT: 80-220k

Los Angeles, CA
Experience 3-8 years
Contract: 40-140hr
FT: 70-170k

Portland, OR
Experience 3-8 years
Contract: 40-120hr
FT: 65-160k

Comment: I'm based in the midwest, and would agree with these numbers with one caveat: anyone working on the 40-50 / hr end either doesn't know what they are worth, or they have been really unlucky, or have some aversion to contract negotiation. I have a couple of friends who occasionally bill this little, and I'm always aghast. I would expect someone with NO experience (but maybe tangential experience, or some apps in the store?) to bill at least $40 / hr.